# How to add formula in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

May I ask if how can i add formula in googlescript? I have a google script here however i would like to automatically add formula with relative reference on the blank part

`targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3]]);`

I need to add this formula
= If (B2 = "","--",COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2))

Here is the full script

```
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var targetSpreadsheetId = "TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  
  var sourceSheetName = "SourceSheetName";
  var targetSheetName = "TargetSheetName"
  
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  
  var selection = sourceSheet.getSelection();
  var selectedRanges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  
  var targetData = [];
  
  selectedRanges.forEach(function (range) {
    var startRow = range.getRow();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 4); // Assuming column B is index 2, column C is index 3, and column D is index 4
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    
    sourceValues.forEach(function (row) {
      targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3]]); // Copying values from column B, C, D to E, A, and F respectively
    });
  });
  
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetData.length, targetData[0].length); // Starting from column A (1)
  targetRange.setValues(targetData);
}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

to automatically add the formula with relative references in Google Apps Script, you can modify the targetData.push() line as follows:

```
targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3], '=IF(B2="", "--", COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2))']);
```

By adding '=IF(B2="", "--", COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2))' as the 7th element in the targetData.push() array, you are inserting the formula into the corresponding cell in the target sheet. The formula uses relative references (B2 and $B$2:B2) to adjust as it is copied to different rows.

Try this script with the added formula:

```
var sourceSpreadsheetId = "SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
var targetSpreadsheetId = "TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID";

var sourceSheetName = "SourceSheetName";
var targetSheetName = "TargetSheetName"

var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);

var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);

var selection = sourceSheet.getSelection();
var selectedRanges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();

var targetData = [];

selectedRanges.forEach(function (range) {
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 4); // Assuming column B is index 2, column C is index 3, and column D is index 4
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  sourceValues.forEach(function (row) {
    targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3], '=IF(B2="", "--", COUNTIF($B$2:B2, B2))']); // Copying values from column B, C, D to E, A, and F respectively and adding the formula
  });
});

var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetData.length, targetData[0].length); // Starting from column A (1)
targetRange.setValues(targetData);
```

With this modification, the formula will be added to the corresponding cell in column A of the target sheet for each row copied from the source sheet. The formula will adjust its references accordingly as it is copied to different rows.

Comment: there any other ways wherein the row on the formula would automatically adjust based on where the formula will pasted/inserted? When i ran the macro multiple times B2 in the formula didn't change

Comment: U can modify it to use the ROW() function to get the current row number.

Try: targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3], '=IF(B' + (targetData.length + 1) + '="", "--", COUNTIF($B$2:B' + (targetData.length + 1) + ', B' + (targetData.length + 1) + '))']);

In this updated formula, targetData.length + 1 is used to dynamically insert the current row no where the formula is being pasted. As the loop iterates through the rows, the formula will auto adjust its references based on the current row no.

Each time you run the macro, the formula will work for the newly inserted rows.